# Need help when echoing an array with objects that contain arrays, in a table

Tags: php, arrays, object, soap

I am building a customer portal. I have to call a SOAP function on a web server that returns an object. In that object there are more objects.

They are like 2nd layer objects.

In the 2nd layer objects there is an array with data, that has to be shown in a table on screen.

In the code I currently have I can't seem to find a way to loop the echo properly.

This is the XML the SOAP call returns:

```
<object>
     <value>string</value>
     <value>string</value>
     <value>string</value>
   <object>
      <value>string</value>
      <value>string</value>
      <value>string</value>
    <object>
      <value>string</value>
      <value>string</value>
      <value>string</value>
    </object>
  </object>
</object>
```

This is my code:

```
  // soapcall returns $response

  $response = (array)$stdClass;
  $_UserData = $response;
  $UserData = (array)$_UserData;

  echo '<table id="table">
          <tr>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>Value</th>
          </tr>';

  foreach ($UserData as $key => $data){
    if (is_object($data)) {
      $array = (array)$data;
      foreach ($array as $key => $data) {
        if (is_object($data)) {

        }
        else {
          echo '<tr><td>' . $key . '</td><td>' . $data . '</td></tr>';
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      echo '<tr><td>' . $key . '</td><td>' . $data . '</td></tr>';
    }
  }
   echo '</table>
    </br>
 <form action="logout.php">
     <button>Log out</button>
 </form>';
```

Is there any way to simplify this loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can echo the object data in the same way:

```
echo '<tr><td>' . $key . '</td><td>' . $data . '</td></tr>';
```

`foreach` statements work with both arrays and objects.

You can also try:

```
echo '<tr><td>' . $key . '</td><td>' . $key->$data . '</td></tr>';
```

Comment: If i do that i get the error message: 'Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in'